# How to design a 12V to <100mV 15A DC-DC converter?

Tags: pcb, dc-dc-converter, magnetics

My project requires a constant current source of at least 13A for a minimum of 1s (preferably capable of longer such as 5s). The primary use of this current is to produce a B-field. The current would be limited by a "dummy" resistive load.

For my solution, I want to reduce the power required to be dissipated in order to reduce PCB space and keep power requirements low. This would be achieved by reducing the resistance and voltage of the circuit. I would prefer to keep power dissipation less than 5W which would mean the output voltage needs to be below 0.38V to achieve the 13A requirement. The system power rail is 12V.

I have looked into using a Buck topology, however, reducing 12V to less than 0.8V is difficult to achieve due to the required voltage reference and resistive losses in the ICs.

What would be a solution to this problem?

Comment: A ratio of over 100 is a bit steep to ask one buck converter to do at 15 A, but not impossible. Have you considered to cascade two buck converters, with about 10x on each?

Comment: Must the B-field be generated from approximately a single turn? Why can't more turns of thinner wire be used?

Comment: @TimWilliams I wonder if it's not a coil. It would be good to know a little more about the field That's not to say you couldn't make a multi-pass setup that looks a lot like a single straight wire (for example)

Answer (score 14):

Your requirements are quite close to the CPU VRM found on a PC motherboard, which outputs around 1V at huge current (50-100A). So you should be able to find the same parts, which are available and cheap.

Unfortunately none of these parts are designed for current regulation. However any voltage output buck converter can be flipped into a contant current output converter by using a fast current sense opamp to pickup voltage on a sense resistor and drive the feedback pin. There are some gotchas, notably your load resistance is very low value so the gain from PWM duty cycle to output current will be quite high, so you'd have to consider loop stability.

There is another solution that is simple, cheap, in stock and always stable: the hysteretic buck current source.

[image]

Basically it's a comparator that monitors current through the buck inductor. When current is too low, it turns the top FET on. When current is too high, it turns it off. The comparator has hysteresis (via resistors). Together with the inductor and input/output voltages, that sets the operating frequency. Inductor current is a sawtooth that oscillates between the two comparator thresholds.

One of these has been driving the LED headlight on my bicycle for years without trouble.

I didn't have a MOSFET driver spice models and didn't search for suitable MOSFETs, so I used switches instead.

Output current is set by a control volage that tweaks comparator threshold via the two resistors on the left.

You'll need a synchronous half bridge MOSFET driver that has a single input (not high and low) and anti cross conduction logic to control both FETs, for example ADP3120, NCP3420, NCP5901, etc. The top FET should be fast, the bottom one should have low RdsON.

With both FET RdsON at 10mOhm, plus components shown on the schematic, efficiency is around 50%, so it wastes 5W to send 16A into the 20Omh loads. That's expected, because there's 10mOhm in the FET, plus a 10mOhm sense resistor, and the load is 20 mOhm, so it can't do better than 50%. In order to do so you'd need lower RdsON for the bottom FET, and a lower value sense resistor... but the comparator needs a large enough signal, so it can't be too low. Inductor losses are not accounted for.

Advantages are simplicity, no loop stability issues, and low cost. The main drawback is that the frequency is variable and depends on pretty much everything, so you have to do the math to set it where you want. Variable frequency also means the output capacitor, which is fixed, will filter the current at high switching frequency and deliver a smooth output. But at low output current (therefore low switching frequency), not so much filtering occurs, so the inductor ripple current goes straight to the load. It is also not very accurate.

In order to have a smooth output current over a wide range, like 100:1 you'd need a fixed frequency converter... but the on-time is going to be extremely tiny due to the input/output ratio.

To reduce losses, you can simply go two-phase (or more):

[image]

Stealing an idea from a [TI appnote](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva170b/snva170b.pdf): the comparator turns off the FET from its own channel, but when it wants to turn it back on, we turn on the FET from the other channel instead, so there's an extra flip flop for that. Then the channels will interleave automatically. This is so cheap it's possible to use more channels: the comparator turns on the next FET (modulo N) instead of its own. With N channels, current is divided by N (per channel), all losses that are in I^2 are divided by N^2 (per channel) thus total losses for all N channels are divided by N.

In order to reduce current ripple, you can use one voltage output buck to convert 12V into a lower voltage that results in setting the duty cycle of this current source close to 50%. Then, with two channels, each inductor will have a sawtooth current that is the opposite phase of the other, and current ripple will cancel (mostly).

Comment: Haven't read the whole answer, but regarding CPU VRMs: they're almost always multi-stage, typically with a central controlling IC. That is a complex design. You're on the right track, but I'd be looking at VRMs targeting embedded ARM SoCs and similar, or maybe thin laptops (in the 15-25W power class).

Comment: Good suggestion! I was mostly thinking about MOSFETs and drivers for PC mobo VRMs, which are available, cheap, and a good fit for 12V input. The controllers are way too complicated for this,

Answer (score 2):

> *I have looked into using a Buck topology, however, reducing 12V to
> less than 0.8V is difficult to achieve due to the required voltage
> reference and resistive losses in the ICs*

Why not use a high-speed amplifier with a gain of 2, 3 or 4 (or whatever) to amplify the output voltage so that it can be used into the feedback pin and achieve decent regulation. A decent op-amp with a gain-bandwidth-product of around 10 MHz should be good enough for this type of application and, there are plenty that are really good on offset voltage errors.

Regarding the peak current and losses, use an IC that has an external MOSFET arrangement to achieve low-power losses.

Answer (score 1):

I already made another answer, but I wasn't satisfied with the poor output current range and high ripple of the hysteretic current source...

[image]

Everyone loves quantity discounts, so this is:

- One 74HC4017 plus oscillator (a few MHz)
- N channels, each with synchronous driver, SMD dual MOSFET (modeled with swicthes in simulation), and inductor (about 50 cents each)
- Input and output caps.

There is no control at all, and each channel turns on with the corresponding output of the HC4017. If N channels are populated, then each channel has 1/N duty cycle.

Properties of this circuit:

- No output current ripple. Inductor currents of each channel sum up to a constant*. (mismatches between channels will still cause ripple, of course).
- DC Transformer: Iout = Iin*N ; Vout = Vin/N

This circuit drives the 20 mOhm load with 0.3V/15A, while appearing to its own power supply as a load requiring 3.2V/1.5A. Just like a transformer, the output load impedance is reflected at the input with a factor N², so the 20 mOhm load is converted into about 2 ohms (minus losses).

The whole point of this circuit is to be the second stage in a two stage solution. As for the first stage, from 12V main supply it is **much** easier to make an efficient switching converter for an output of 3.2V 1.5A than 0.3V 15A. Duty cycle is a lot more "user-friendly", I²R losses are much better, etc.

According to the simulator, efficiency is pretty high (80-90%).

There are two options to control the output current:

- Vary input voltage and count on coil and MOSFET resistance to set current: inaccurate, but simple
- Power it from a constant current source, with a smoothing cap between the two. A buck LED driver chip could be an option, or just a bench supply in constant current mode.
- Hall effect sensor to check the B field you want to generate, then feedback to the first stage (either current or voltage output) for regulation.

Of course you can use less channels. You need at least two for the "zero current ripple" feature. To make the first stage's job much easier, you need more. Fortunately, the per channel BOM cost is low.

Comment: by "50c synchronous driver" etc you mean 50¢? It's not immediately obvious.

Comment: Yes, I don't have ¢ on my French keyboard XD

Comment: American keyboards don't either. In fact, I'm not aware of *any* keyboard that does; I just make heavy use of [compose](http://wincompose.info/) [sequences](https://wiki.debian.org/XCompose).